# Do Data and Nonce both play a role in hash?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, hash, nonce

If a transaction's hash doesn't change with `data` it makes blockchain mutable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A transaction hash is based on a transaction's `data` and `nonce` fields, among others. You can read about how transaction hashes are generated [here](https://medium.com/@codetractio/inside-an-ethereum-transaction-fa94ffca912f).

A transaction hash is "mutable" (by definition), until is is included in a block on-chain. Once the transaction has been included in a block, it is immutable, as it lives on-chain and cannot be edited.

I'd like to clarify that any parameter of a transaction (`to`, `value`, etc.) is and will be mutable until the point it is included in a block on-chain.

Comment: thanks a lot i am exploring blockchain and your answer helped me a lot.